# allowedOrigins not working in akka http server

Tags: scala, xmlhttprequest, cors, akka-http

I've setup an akka http server on localhost with port 8091. I am sending data to it from client side using XMLHttpRequest POST but it is showing warning that my cross-origin request is blocked because "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is not present. So, I added CORS support to it. My code looks like :

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers.HttpOriginRange.*
import ch.megard.akka.http.cors.CorsDirectives._
import ch.megard.akka.http.cors.CorsSettings
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Collector{

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   implicit val system = ActorSystem("collector")
   implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
   implicit val defaultDispatcher = system.dispatcher
   val settings = CorsSettings.defaultSettings.copy(allowedOrigins = *)
   val routes: Route = cors(settings) {
     path("event") {
       post {
          parameters('uuid.as[String], 'url.as[String]) { (uuid, url) =>
        complete {
          Future {
            println("Data is received")
            println("UUID is : " + uuid + " & URL is : " + url)
            System.currentTimeMillis().toString
          }
         }
       }
     }
    }
  }
  Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "localhost", 8091)
  println("server started at 8091")
 }
}
```

But still my requests are blocked and I am not able to see any data on server also. It is working if I send POST request from terminal via curl command. 
In the network tab, it is showing 404 status. I am not able to understand why it is showing such behavior. 
Please guide me what I am doing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by changing the way I am sending XMLHttpRequest. 
Now my code looks like :

```
val xhr = new dom.XMLHttpRequest()
val url="http://localhost:8090/event?&uuid="+dom.window.localStorage.getItem("uuid")+"&url="+dom.window.localStorage.getItem("url") 
xhr.open("POST",url )
xhr.send()
```

instead of -

```
val xhr = new dom.XMLHttpRequest()
val url="http://localhost:8090/event
xhr.open("POST",url ) 
xhr.send(s"uuid=${dom.window.localStorage.getItem("uuid")}&url=${dom.window.localStorage.getItem("url")}")
```